# find command with variable in it

Tags: bash, shell

I want to do this: `readarray var1 < <(find "/path/to/dir" \( $var2 \) | sort)`

```
echo $var2
user@domain:~# -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.mkv"
```

Unfortunately, my script does not work. Please, tell me where I do a mistake.

Comment: I'd be interested in why you need the sorting of the results. You cold get this in the `zsh` shell in a much more convenient and safe way which would not rely on the pathnames being sane (containing no newlines).

Comment: @Kusalananda Just I'm newer in Linux (more precisely in Ubuntu). if you are telling me that your case is better I will be glad to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array:

```
var2=( -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.mkv" )

readarray var1 < <(find "/path/to/dir" \( "${var2[@]}" \) | sort)
```

See the somewhat related [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: Can I do it without array? Only variable. Is it possibly?

Comment: @UnixUser You'd better let us know why you wouldn't want to use an array.  Using an array is the correct way of handling this.

Comment: ... you're already using an array for `var1`, so it's not like you could port this code to a shell that doesn't support arrays

Comment: @Kusalananda I want to understand what options I have. Thanks too.

Answer (score 0):

To get all names beneath the path `/path/to/dir` as a sorted list in `bash`:

```bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob

names=( /path/to/dir/** )
```

The `globstar` shell option in `bash` enables the use of the `**` glob, which works similarly as `*` but matches across `/` in pathnames (i.e., it matches "recursively" down into directories).  The `nullglob` shell option makes it so that if a shell glob does *not* match any name, it is removed completely (the default is to keep the unexpanded pattern).  The `dotglob` option causes hidden filenames to be matched by default.

The resulting expansion of a shell glob is lexicographically ordered, as is the default output of `sort`, so no piping of names to `sort` is necessary.

To get the names that has the filename suffixes `.avi` or `.mkv`, use

```bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob extglob

names=( /path/to/dir/**/*.@(avi|mkv) )
```

Here, I've added the `extglob` shell option, which allows for using extended globbing pattern.  The pattern `@(avi|mkv)` means "either `avi` or `mkv`", so the full pattern would match any name beneath `/path/to/dir` that ends with either `.avi` or `.mkv`.  The resulting array would be sorted.

---

`find` would be useful if you need to do things with the found names, or if you need to incorporate specific filetype tests.  For example, if you need to make sure you're only matching only *regular files*, use

```
find /path/to/dir -type f \( -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.mkv' \)
```

Given the two filename suffixes `avi` and `mkv` in an array called `suffix`, the `-name` tests can be constructed as an array:

```bash
suffix=( avi mkv )

nametest=( -false )  # assumes GNU find here

for suf in "${suffix[@]}"; do
    nametest+=( -o -name ".$suf" )
done

find /path/to/dir -type f \( "${nametest[@]}" \)
```

It is almost never correct to save the *output* of `find` in a variable when you actually want to *do things* to the found names.  Instead, use `-exec` to carry out the action:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f \( "${nametest[@]}" \) -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        # do something with "$pathname" here
    done' sh {} +
```

For further reading, see

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)
- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)
- Many other questions and answers regarding [find](/questions/tagged/find) on this site.

Comment: Hm... How I understand `names=( /path/to/dir/**/*.@(avi|mkv) )` First part is for `zsh` ? And really, It is easier, but can your case be more dynamic? I mean `names=( /path/to/dir/**/*.@(avi|mkv) )` . Can I use a variable type of array (or another) instead `@(avi|mkv)` ? Just I save suffixes to variable and use in another part of code too.